# Cumulative Percentage stuck at 0.00% at the first roll

Tags: python, percentage, calculation

I wrote a code which gives the stats of 1,000,000 games of craps. I calculated the percentage of the total games that were won and lost, and also the the **cumulative percentage** of the total games played that were won or lost up to and including a given number of rolls **(column 3 of the output)**

The problem is that it keep giving me `0.00%` on the first roll, why is that happening?

The code where I calculate the cumulative percentage:

```
for i in range(0, len(rolls)):
    p_resolved = rolls[i]*100/craps_game_number
    c_resolved = 100*sum(rolls[0:i])/craps_game_number

    if i!=len(rolls)-1:
        print('{:>5}{:>19.2f}%{:>19.2f}%'.format(i+1,p_resolved,c_resolved))
    else:
        print('{:>5}{:>19.2f}%{:>19.2f}%'.format(i + 1, p_resolved, 100*sum(rolls)/craps_game_number))
```

[image]

Here is the whole code if needed:

```
import random

def win_or_lose():
    roll = random.randint(1,6)+random.randint(1,6)
    if roll in [7,11]:
        return 'Win',1 # return the outcome and attempts it took to decide
    elif roll in [2,3,12]:
        return 'Loss',1
    else:
        attempts=1
        my_point=roll
        while True:
            roll=random.randint(1,6)+random.randint(1,6)
            attempts+=1 # add 1 until the outcome is decided
            if roll==my_point:
                return 'Win',attempts # return the outcome and rounds
            elif roll==7:
                return 'Loss',attempts # return the outcome and rounds
            else:
                continue

rolls = [0]*25
wins=loss=0
craps_game_number=1000000
for _ in range(craps_game_number):
    outcome,attempts = win_or_lose() # store the outcome and rounds it took to decide
    if outcome=='Win':
        wins+=1
    else:
        loss+=1
    if attempts<=len(rolls):
        rolls[attempts-1]+=1
    else:
        rolls[-1]+=1

print('Percentage of wins: {:.2f}%'.format(wins*100/(craps_game_number)))
print('Percentage of losses: {:.2f}%'.format(loss*100/(craps_game_number)))
print('Percentage of wins/losses based on total number of rolls')
print()
print('{:>25}{:>20} '.format('% Resolved','Cummulative %'))
print('{:<5}{:>20} {:>20}'.format('Rolls','on this roll','of games resolved'))

for i in range(0, len(rolls)):
    p_resolved = rolls[i]*100/craps_game_number
    c_resolved = 100*sum(rolls[0:i])/craps_game_number

    if i!=len(rolls)-1:
        print('{:>5}{:>19.2f}%{:>19.2f}%'.format(i+1,p_resolved,c_resolved))
    else:
        print('{:>5}{:>19.2f}%{:>19.2f}%'.format(i + 1, p_resolved, 100*sum(rolls)/craps_game_number))
```

Comment: Looks like an off-by-one error on the bounds of your cumulative calculation. Try replacing `c_resolved = 100*sum(rolls[0:i])/craps_game_number` with `c_resolved = 100*sum(rolls[0:i + 1])/craps_game_number`.

Comment: I was just about to comment the same thing.  On the first iteration `i` is zero, so `rolls[0:i]` is an empty list, the sum of which is zero.

Comment: Omg, Idk how I didn't notice that.

Comment: You're not alone, there's a Wikipedia page on this kind of error here <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error>. Feel free to accept an answer if your question was resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change this line:

```py
c_resolved = 100*sum(rolls[0:i])/craps_game_number
```

... to this:

```py
c_resolved = 100*sum(rolls[0:i + 1])/craps_game_number
```

... you should get output that is something like this, which I think is what the question is asking for:

```
               % Resolved       Cummulative %
Rolls        on this roll    of games resolved
    1              33.35%              33.35%
    2              18.80%              52.15%
    3              13.49%              65.64%
    4               9.64%              75.28%
    5               6.91%              82.19%
    6               4.98%              87.16%
    7               3.57%              90.73%
    8               2.58%              93.31%
    9               1.85%              95.16%
   10               1.35%              96.51%
   11               0.97%              97.48%
   12               0.69%              98.17%
   13               0.50%              98.67%
   14               0.36%              99.03%
   15               0.26%              99.29%
   16               0.19%              99.48%
   17               0.14%              99.62%
   18               0.10%              99.72%
   19               0.08%              99.80%
   20               0.05%              99.85%
   21               0.04%              99.89%
   22               0.03%              99.92%
   23               0.02%              99.94%
   24               0.02%              99.96%
   25               0.04%             100.00%
```

This will make the first line of cumulative result non-zero, and should also correct the values of all subsequent lines prior to the last one (which was getting set to 100% via special-case logic).